# how can I rewrite a push with a map by executing a slice?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops, grid

I would like to know if it is possible to change this push loop with a simple map.

the aim is to create chunks from an array of objects based on the number of columns and rows of a grid.

**for example:** if I have **two rows** and **two columns** the array of objects is divided into an array (chunks = []) in the following way:

```
 const row = 2;
 const col = 2;
 const pages = [
       {id:'one', name:'page_1', active:false},
       {id:'two', name:'page_2', active:false},
       {id:'three', name:'page_2', active:false},
       {id:'four', name:'page_4', active:false},
       {id:'five', name:'page_5', active:false},
    ]
```

**"Chunks"** should come this way:

```
 let chunks = [
   //grid 1 whit max col * row element
   [
       {id:'one', name:'page_1', active:false},
       {id:'two', name:'page_2', active:false},
       {id:'three', name:'page_2', active:false},
       {id:'four', name:'page_4', active:false},
   ],
  //grid 1 whit max col * row element
   [
       {id:'five', name:'page_5', active:false}, 
   ],
 ]
```

I have done it this way and this works well. But I wonder if it's possible to edit and improve everything using only a map instead of a push.

```
    const pages = [
       {id:'one', name:'page_1', active:false},
       {id:'two', name:'page_2', active:false},
       {id:'three', name:'page_2', active:false},
       {id:'four', name:'page_4', active:false},
       {id:'five', name:'page_5', active:false},
    ]
    const row = 2;
    const col = 2;
    let rowIndex = 0;
    let chunkIndex = 0;
    let chunks = [];
    while (row !== rowIndex) {
      chunks.push(page.slice(chunkIndex, chunkIndex + col));
      chunkIndex += col;
      rowIndex += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Not really, `.map` is for transforming one array into another, where the elements are one-to-one, which is not your goal here. Your current code is quite reasonable.

Comment: Seem filter() is a good try. But I'm not sure your logic of dividing, so cant give sample code.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe -  if you want to give me an example I can better explain the division logic. basically i have an array of objects with x values, and i have to divide these objects into another array of arrays, each internal array contains y elements, where y = col * row. so a 10 objects, if I have a col * row = 2 it generates an array with 5 arrays inside which in turn have 2 elements inside (2 objects).